# Does Selle Italia Flite Genuine Gel have rigid shell?

Tags: saddle

I am asking for version **without** a cutout. The question is about the shell (not the padding) -- when you press with your hand in the middle of the saddle (from top to down, like you would sit on it) -- does the shell flex?

*Please note, I am not asking about opinion/recommendation, just data about stiffness of this particular saddle.*

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yes I had a Selle Italia Flite Genuine Gel this summer and it was **very** stiff and rigid...it was wonderful.

Comment: If you owned this saddle, you would know better than this. If you are making up answers, please move on.

Answer (score 2):

There is approximately 5mm of gel padding, over a reasonably flexible base on the Flite Gel. I would not consider it an especially rigid saddle.